# Augmented Reality SDKS

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, augmented-reality

I have been scoping around for something interesting to do in my free time and discovered a thing called augmented reality.

Basically, I’d like to hear your views on a few questions I have and maybe if you could talk a bit about your experience developing AR applications. I am looking at developing a iPhone/iOS application.

1. Does anybody know any simple AR sdks for iphone that are powerful and simple to use?
2. Is it at all possible to get the exact coordinates from a camera? IE: I aim my phone at the table and ‘place’ an AR monster there. Then I can come back tomorrow and the monster will still be there.
3. Any good tutorials to get me started off?
4. Would it be worth it using the FLAR toolkit and using AIR to deploy to mobile?
   Obviously, I’ve put a lot of research into this already. But any help, even if it’s just links you found on google to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Scope around a bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=augmented+reality+[iOS]

Comment: I have looked around. But what im looking for is opinions on your experiences, not just a generic "My toolkit can do this or that and yours cant"

Comment: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks this link have every SDK for iOS,android,blackberry and so on....

Answer (score 2):

I've forked [ARKit for augmented reality in iOS](https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit), and added lots of improvements (such as a radar, range limiter, better looking callouts etc...). It's really easy to integrate, and there's a demo app I've bundled with the code:

[iPhone-AR-Toolkit](https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit)

Comment: Great job on this! Does it support displaying a point at a given elevation? Say PT1: lat1,long1, 30degrees elevation. PT2: lat2,long2,15degrees elevation etc... For something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602190/camera-overlay-change-with-bearing-and-elevation

Answer (score 1):

Check the [AugmentedKit](http://www.augmentedkit.com) they are providing SDK samples, including Augemented reality game sample. I think that's what your are looking for.

Comment: It is not open source. There are a bunch of open source AR SDKs available to poke around.

Answer (score 1):

1) The best AR SDK to poke around is [Qualcomm's Vuforia SDK](http://ar.qualcomm.at)
They provide samples for single image tracking, multiple image tracking, overlaying videos etc.
I think they not provide Geo-Location based AR Demo. For that you need to poke around a bit.

2) For location based AR, you can check out [Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com). They do provide freeware to poke around.

3) [Wikipedia lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_augmented_reality_software) all the available software for AR along with the links. You can check 'em out and explore more. FYI: I am one of the developers of [Alive App](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alive_app) listed on this page.

4) FLAR is flash based. I suggest you to explore more options as suggested above and by other users.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For android:

Android Studio provides own SDK for android development. Layar and Wikitude – Android. AFAIK, Wikitude and Layar have made their SDKs public.

For iOS:

iOS, Metaio SDK which has been acquired by Apple now. you can make use of Craft SDK.

Answer (score 0):

1
You have many options some of them are 
**Free tools**

Junaio

**commercial tools**
metaio SDK
ARToolkit SDK for iOS

2
AS far as I can understand you are asking for a GPS based AR experience. From above mentioned toolkits Junaio supports that feature.
 I think   FLAR toolkit does not support this. It supports marker based and NFT based AR
http://www.artoolworks.com/products/web/flartoolkit-2/

3
Above mentioned toolkits have good documentations you can start from there.

4
This clearly depends on your requirements. FLAR toolkit is not specifically for mobile. So you will have to integrate it to mobile. The frameworks I mentioned are specifically for mobiles including iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Please check vuforia,wikitude and metaio SDK you will get some good information/tutorial about AR, because they given good sample application to get start off for iOS and Android.