# camera overlay change with bearing and elevation

Tags: ios, camera, overlay, augmented-reality

Folks,

I am trying to get a utility as shown in the picture below. Basically the camera display window covers part of the device's screen and a list of points that are connected by a curve or straight line are presented over the camera view as an overlay. I understand this can be drawn using quartz but this is less than half of my problem.

The real issue is that the overlay should present different points as the bearing and elevation changes.

For example:

- if the bearing has to change +5 degrees and elevation +2 degrees, then **PT1** will be next to the right edge of the camera view, **PT2** will also move to the right and **PT3** will be visible.
- Another movement that changes the bearing +10 degrees would make *PT1* not visible, **PT2** at the right, **PT3** middle and **PT4** on the left edge of the camera view.

My questions after the picture:

[image: Picture describing what I am trying to accomplish]

1. Is it possible to have a view that is substantially larger than the size of the camera view (as shown below) and use some methods (I need to research these) to move the view when bearing/elevation changes? Is it recommended performance wise?
2. Is quartz the way to go here? What else do I need (other then of course AVFoundation for the camera and corelocation/motion)? Since my application is only iOS 7 I can use any new methods/APIs exclusive to iOS 7.
3. Aside from [raywendelrich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone) tutorial on the augmented reality game, are there any tutorials that you know of that could help me with this endeavor?

Comment: Folks, it says that bounty is gone after 7 days. will I get back the 50 rep if my question doesn't get a good answer?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) for bounty informations

Comment: @rkh did you manage to get your bounty back?

Comment: @Unheilig, you can not get it back. Check out the link posted by Samoth

Comment: @rkh So if you tilt the device forward (away from the user's body), the view with alpha will scroll down based on the amount of tilt??

Is it similar in terms of movement navigation to that of having to handle a wooden 3d maze to navigate the ball further into the middle based on tilt movements? If that's not what you're trying to do, please tell us what the end goal is and what it is you're actually trying to achieve in the wider perspective since if I've gotten it wrong then your explanation wasn't clear enough. If I was correct from what I understood then we can talk about it further.

Comment: @rkh After having given what I think might have been similar to something you are trying to do, I re read your post and I am feeling confident in understanding your ultimate goal. So i refine what I said to the following, You want to be able to move your camera overlay in the direction of the iOS device's compass to get a full 360 rotation - bearing, and tilting the device left and right should reveal either side of the views? And you just have a few questions about implementation?

Comment: Hi @Pavan. Basically yes that is what I am trying to achieve. I never got around to do that yet but I'll explain more here. Think of the points as items that are high on a wall in front of you. If you hold your device parallel to your body you can't see them. You have to tilt the device UP to make the objects/points visible. You may also need to tilt the device left and right since they may be outside the view of the camera. Yes, I have no idea where to start with the implementation.

Comment: @Pavan this is one example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRLpKZMCRHo ... In the video the user is just moving left and right but it is possible to move up and have the curve in the video be centered (or disappear if you move way up) in your screen....

Comment: @rkh the user is not simply moving just left and right, he is tilting up and down too, how else are those satellites enteringthe scene? its through up and down tilt - pitch. So yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Pavan, I know up/down/left/right. that's what I am saying. I also know it is possible since these guys did it and stargaze or some other app also did it... Question is how?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following, each article or link has different key things required to make your final product. You eventually will be using a combination of geolocation, the compass/or the iphone's gyroscope data coming in.

Reading all the references combined and implementing them one by one in different projects will give you a solid start on how to then combine it all together to create your application. But first you need to get a solid understanding on how to manipulate the knowledge you will learn and how you can then apply it to create your project.

**References:**

A cool project from Ray Winderlech teach you how to use location gps coordinates in your application

- [Augmented reality location based tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based)

The next two links show you how to grab gyroscope data to find out the pitch, yaw and rotation and find out the device current position in space.

- [Apple gyroscope example app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245733/apple-gyroscope-sample-code)
- [Another core motion gyroscope example](http://cs491f10.wordpress.com/2010/10/28/core-motion-gyroscope-example/)

Will teach you how to use the compass

- [Ray Winderlichs augmented reality compass tutorial for ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/augmented-reality-tutorial-for-ios)

Here's some more augmented reality stuff on overlaying stuff on the camera view

- [iPhone AR Toolkit](https://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit)
- [Augmented reality marker tracking tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/40870/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-marker-tracking)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these next weekend (I am finish another app for a customer at the moment) and see what I can come up with... I was hoping to find a tutorial that incorporates all what I need in one place but I guess it is very hard for anyone to do it in one place... I agree I need a solid knowledge of the independent topics to be able to do this. It is considered high advanced stuff...

Comment: @rkh, no problem. glad I could help. So do you email or something? email me at kataria.pavan@gmail.com